# How to use browser.wait command in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, protractor

I have my test-data(element finder and element ids) in json file and parsing in my test scripts to perform the test. The issue I have here is , I put browser.sleep after each element for the respective element to occur on the DOM. but I want to replace that browser.sleep with browser.wait since browser.sleep is not the best practice. below is my code. please give your suggestions how to replace browser.sleep with wait command.

```
var controlData = require("../../TestData/EmailForm/e2e_Test.json");
        var controlKeys;
        var respose;
        var testData;

        function(callback){
            controlKeys=["BtnEmailChkBox","BtnUpdate","TrueEmailGetAttribute"];
            async.eachSeries(controlKeys,function(key,next){
                commands.execute(testConfig,controlData[key],function(err,res){
                    respose = res[0].data;
                    testData = controlData[key].actions[0].data;
                    expect(respose).toEqual(testData);
                    browser.sleep(5000);
                    next();
                });
            },function(err){
                callback();
            })
        },
```

Comment: use the [documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write custom wait function as utils for you test or you could write it directly. For this purpose `Protractor` provide [`browser.wait()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) function.

First argument is a function predicate, you could take a look at predefined functions in [ExpectedConditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions) namespace.

Second one is optional and define how long to wait for the condition to be true.

Third one is also optional and define the message to use if the wait times out.

```
browser.wait(
  ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(your_element),
  how_long_you_want_to_wait_in_ms
  optional_third_parameter_could_be_error_message
)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: As i mentioned on my main post , browser.sleep is not a good practice to follow. To avoid that i am using browser.wait. Please find the code below i used browser.wait.                                                                                        
`const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;   browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($(myPlan.elements().btnNext)), 5000);`